# {nativescript} accessing SmsManager

Tags: android, nativescript

I want to access android smsManager with using nativescript as shown on code below. When I running my app, it thrown an error with message Failed resolving constructor on class android.telephony.SmsManager. 
Please help with this error

```
exports.sendSMSManager = function(args) {
    var smsManager = new android.telephony.SmsManager();
    var messageToSend = "Tes123";
    var phoneNum = "085396175111";
    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, messageToSend, null,null);    
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mike, it doesn't work either

Comment: For your purposes you could use the existing plugin `nativescript-messenger` which provides the functionality to send SMS

Comment: @NikolayTsonev, it's an awesome plugin but doesn't meet my need. i'm already install that plugin but it's just open sms app with my message and doesn't automatically send it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to initialize SMS messenger and send message.

```
var sms = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage("0888001001", null, "Sent from Android", null, null);
```

However for Android SDK versions >= 23 you will have to explicitly grant permissions for **android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS**

You can use [this plugin for explicit permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-permissions)